# ACAccountCredential returns null for oauthToken

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, social-framework, acaccount

I am getting access to user's facebook via:

```
[accStore requestAccessToAccountsWithType:fbAccountType
                                           options:options
                                        completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {
                                            if (granted) {
                                                // If access granted, then get the Facebook account info
                                                NSArray *accounts = [accStore
                                                                     accountsWithAccountType:fbAccountType];
                                                ACAccount *acc = [accounts lastObject];

                                                // Get the access token, could be used in other scenarios
                                                ACAccountCredential *fbCredential = [acc credential];
                                                NSString *accessToken = [fbCredential oauthToken];
                                                NSLog(@"Facebook Access Token: %@", accessToken);


                                                // Add code here to make an API request using the SLRequest class

                                            } else {
                                                NSLog(@"Access not granted");
                                            }
                                        }];
```

This prints out:

```
 Facebook Access Token: (null)
```

I am granted access, but the token is null. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: i'm experiencing the same thing. did you ever find a solution? I couldn't reproduce myself but could with another teammate's phone. I found that if we went into Settings, disabled facebook access for our app and then immediately enabled it, we would then get a token.

Comment: I am experiencing the same thing. But only on my iPhone. It works on other iPhone.

Answer (score 4):

I've solved the problem by renewing the credentials. That is, after access to FB has been granted, but in the case where ACAccountCredential's **oauthToken** returns nil, we just call ACAccountStore's **renewCredentialsForAccount**. Credentials are renewed, and after that the token is valid!

Answer (score 1):

Here's some info from Apple doc:

> @property(nonatomic, retain) ACAccountCredential *credential
>   Discussion This property is required and must be set before the
>   account is saved. For privacy reasons, this property is inaccessible
>   after the account is saved.

As in your code, [acc credential] will return null

For reference, http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Accounts/Reference/ACAccountClassRef/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011019

Found a similar post here: [Get Facebook access token from Social.framework(iOS6)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13930371/get-facebook-access-token-from-social-frameworkios6)

Hope this can help.

Comment: If you take look at the code in the link you provided, the code is the exact same. I am using the EXACT same code in the answer of the link.